# As I create a string in C with the exact size of the word entered by console

Tags: c

I am new to C and I was wondering how I can do so that when a word of X characters is entered through the console, an array of characters is created with the right memory allocation for it, for example I enter "hello" and it is saved in a string of 6-space characters.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the [ISO C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) specification or Microsoft C library that directly does what you seek.

In the [C POSIX library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library), however <sub>([what's the difference?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/359577/60495))</sub>, the [`scanf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) family of functions support an `m` modifier for string `s` inputs. When `m` is used, `scanf()` will *allocate* a buffer of an appropriate size, and assign it to the *pointer* that you provide:

From the [Linux `scanf()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> An optional 'm' character. This is used with string conversions (`%s`, `%c`, `%[`), and relieves the caller of the need to allocate a corresponding buffer to hold the input: instead, `scanf()` allocates a buffer of sufficient size, and assigns the address of this buffer to the corresponding pointer argument, which should be **a pointer to** a `char *` variable (this variable does not need to be initialized before the call).  The caller should subsequently `free(3)` this buffer when it is no longer required.

Here's an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *input = NULL;

    if (scanf("%ms", &input) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("scanf() allocated string: \"%s\"\n", input);

    free(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Supported C libraries:

- [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) -- [since 2.7](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-alpha/2007-10/msg00045.html) ([267c54dcef41](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=267c54dcef41ab0ee383b208117b35b3e9d5665c))
- [musl](https://musl.libc.org/) -- [since 0.9.11](https://musl.libc.org/releases.html) ([16a1e036](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/?id=16a1e0365d83c387d0dddd3c127ac7c8dcdf17fc))

*Unsupported* C libraries:

- [dietlibc](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/) -- as of at least 0.34
- [Microsoft C runtime library (CRT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/c-run-time-library-reference)

Comment: True, yet "There is nothing the ISO C that supports this." overstates.  Certainly possible - with enough code.

Comment: Reworded to make it clear I'm referring to the *standard library*.

Comment: Additional note that `"... scanf() allocates a buffer of sufficient size ..."` makes no guarantee that the buffer is limited to the exact size necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looked interesting to try to directly meet OP's goal of <enter "hello" and it is saved in a string of 6-space character> using standard library functions, even if it took some code.

Sadly standard C does not offer the nice option as suggested with [@Jonathon Reinhart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69563947/2410359) good answer.

Instead, below is an approach not suited for learners, but does the job.  It does not have a prior line length limit.  It recursively forms a link list of characters entered (recursion not suitable for a *long* line), then allocates an array based on depth, and assigns the array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct link_s {
  struct link_s *prev;
  char ch;
} llink;

char* foo(llink *prior) {
  int ch = fgetc(stdin);
  if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r' || ch == EOF) {
    llink *ll = prior;
    size_t len = 1;
    while (ll) {
      len++;
      ll = ll->prev;
    }
    char *buf = malloc(len);
    if (buf) {
      buf[--len] = '\0';
      llink *ll = prior;
      while (ll) {
        buf[--len] = ll->ch;
        ll = ll->prev;
      }
    }
    return buf;
  }
  llink node = {.prev = prior, .ch = (char) ch};
  return foo(&node);
}

int main() {
  char *s = foo(NULL);
  printf("<%s>\n", s);
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Input

```
Hello<enter>
```

Output

```
<Hello>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to read until a newline, you can use [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) defined in `stdio.h`. It does automatic memory allocation. The function will allocate an extra character to store the newline, you can remove it using `buf[strcspn(buf, '\n')] = '\0'`.

If you want it to read until a whitespace, sad to say there's no standard C library function to meet your needs for arbitrary string lengths (without writing a bunch of your own code). If you are a beginner learning C and need simple I/O, using `scanf("%s", buf)` into a fixed sized buffer should be plenty.